# What was the exact wording from Ivanhoe of this advice on how to free yourself from slavery?

Tags: quote-source, sir-walter-scott, ivanhoe

> All you need to free yourself from slavery is a couple of pints of beer

I read Ivanhoe for the first time translated into Spanish, and am having a heck of time finding the material in any English editions for reference.

Answer (score 11):

Scott made his Saxons drink ‘ale’, not ‘beer’. In doing so he was following the Saxons’ own usage: the word ‘beer’ was “rare, except in poetry, and it seems to have become common only in the 16th century” (*OED*). So you are looking for this piece of dialogue:

> “Thou art an ass,” replied one of the thieves; “three quarts of double ale had rendered thee as free as thy master, ay, and freer too, if he be a Saxon like thyself.”
>
> <sub>Walter Scott (1819). [*Ivanhoe*, chapter XI](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/82/82-h/82-h.htm#link2HCH0011).</sub>